# How to use LineLegend and SwatchLegend together

Tags: legending

I am wondering if one can place on the right of the plot frame a single legend that is a combination of a LineLegend and a SwatchLegend.

What I want is to see the line with its label on top of the swatch with its label as if the swatch was the second item of a LineLegend.

I have tried

```
 PlotLegends -> {LineLegend[{Blue}, {"first item"}, 
     LabelStyle -> {Bold, 20}], 
     SwatchLegend[{Opacity[0.3, Blue]}, {"second item"}]}
```

and some variations with Join[] but I have not succeded to put all these legends on the right of the frame. For instance the code above places one legend on the right and one at the bottom, which is not what I want.

Is this merge possible or I should write something from scratch?

Thanks for your inputs,
Roberto

Answer (score 7):

Additional alternatives to mix different legends:

```
lg1 = SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"sin"}];
lg2 = LineLegend[{Blue}, {"cos"}];
lg3 = PointLegend[{Green}, {"sinc"},   LegendMarkers -> "\[FilledCircle]"];

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], 2 Sinc[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
     PlotStyle -> Thread[{Thick, {Red, Blue, Green}}], ImageSize -> 400,
     PlotLegends -> (Placed[#, Right] & /@ {lg1, lg2, lg3})]
```

[image]

or `PlotLegends -> {{lg1, Right}, {lg2, Right}, {lg3, Right}}`

or  `PlotLegends -> Column[{lg1, lg2, lg3}]]` (as in Roberto's answer)

And a few alternative ways to use `Legended` in addition to the method in ubpdqn's answer:

```
Legended[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], 2 Sinc[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Thread[{Thick, {Red, Blue, Green}}], ImageSize -> 400], 
   (Placed[#, Right] & /@ {lg1, lg2, lg3})]
```

Alternatively, use `Column[{lg1, lg2, lg3}]]` or `{{lg1, Right}, {lg2, Right}, {lg3, Right}}` in the second argument of `Legended`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this contrived example will be helpful:

```
lleg = LineLegend[{Red}, {"sin"}];
sleg = SwatchLegend[{Blue}, {"cos"}];
Legended[Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  ListPlot[Table[{j, Cos[j]}, {j, 0 , 2 Pi, 0.11}]]], 
 Framed[Column[{lleg, sleg}], RoundingRadius -> 10, 
  Background -> LightBlue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The legends need to go into a Column[] ...

```
 PlotLegends -> 
  Column[{LineLegend[{Blue}, {"First"},], 
   SwatchLegend[{Opacity[0.3, Blue]}, {"Second"}, 
   ]}]
```