# Mix of lines and markers in PlotLegend in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

Using PlotLegend I would like to show a legend with a mix of lines and markers

see example data and plot command

```
x = Range[1, 10];
list1 = x^2;
list2 = {1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 8, 2, 8, 9, 4};
list3 = 2 x + 7;
list4 = 15 x - x^2;

ListPlot[{Thread[{x, list1}], Thread[{x, list2}], Thread[{x, list3}], 
Thread[{x, list4}]}, Joined -> {True, True, True, False}, 
PlotMarkers -> {"", "", "", Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled@0.02]}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "Example "}, 
PlotLegends -> {"list 1", "list 2", "list 3", "list 4"}]
```

This creates the plot 
[image: Example Plot]

which is almost what I am after, except I want the circular marker to be evident in the legend.

In the past you could not do this with PlotLegend - I am hoping that this has changed with newer versions of Mathematica.

Here's a solution where you need to manually set all the line colours etc. 
 [How to use LineLegend and SwatchLegend together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51570/how-to-use-linelegend-and-swatchlegend-together) (this is several years old - why I am essentially re-asking the question)

Is anyone aware of a way to do this within a single plot command, so that I do not have to manually set all the line colours etc and can use the underlying defaults?

If the answer is no - that would be good to know, I'll go the manual route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
ListPlot[
    {list1, list2, list3, list4},
    Joined->{True,True,True,False},
    PlotMarkers->{"","","",{Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0,0}]}],.02}},
    PlotStyle->Thick,Frame->True,ImageSize->Large,
    FrameLabel->{{"y",None},{"x","Example"}},
    PlotLegends->LineLegend[
        {"list1", "list2", "list3", "list4"},
        LegendMarkerSize->{20,8}
    ]
]
```

[image]