# Combining LineLegend and BarLegend in CountourPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

So I am having a similar problem to the one in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51570/how-to-use-linelegend-and-swatchlegend-together) but the solutions therein are of no use.

Consider a basic ContourPlot with an automatic BarLegend

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], 
Epilog -> {{Red, Line[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0., 3., .1}]]}}]
```

which gives the following, nice ContourPlot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW3fK.jpg

However, when I try and add a LineLegend for the Epilog, ContourPlot cannot do so automatically. I have tried all suggestions in the link above and none of them work

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> 
 Column[{BarLegend[Automatic], 
LineLegend[{Directive[Red]}, {"Test"}]}], 
Epilog -> {{Red, Line[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0., 3., .1}]]}}]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gmXW.jpg

How do I fix this? I want the BarLegend to be automatic, since it provides a nice, simple fit of values. However, even manually I have had no success with BarLegend not evaluating.

(As a sidenote, imgur is not accepting the pictures I have provided. Have put up links, if someone can fix, would be grateful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PlotLegends` can take a list of legends:

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {
        BarLegend[Automatic], 
        Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Red]}, {"Test"}], After]
        }, 
    Epilog -> {{Red, Line[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0., 3., .1}]]}}]
```

By default one legend will go to the right, and one below, so I used `Placed` to put both on the right.

Comment: I swear I tried placing a list in PlotLegends, but I can't see what mistake I made, I believe Column was the problem. Have now amended your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work-around using separate `ContourPlot`s:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]];

p2 = ContourPlot[y == Cos[x], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Test"}]];

Show[p1, p2]
```

Will this be ok?

Comment: `Placed` is not necessary since `Show` knows how to combine `Legended` with legends at the same position, although you can use it to fine tune the positioning. Also, you don't need to specify the color with `LineLegend`, `LineLegend[{"Test"}]` does exactly what you want, and you only have to specify the color in one place.

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks for the simplifications! I will modify my answer :)

Comment: Actually, Show and Legended is the correct way of doing it:     Show[Legended[p1, LineLegend[{Directive[Red]}, {"Test"}]]]

Comment: I think both are "correct", but use the one you find most suitable of course :)

Comment: @OldTomMorris I agree with Marius, both are correct, the `Legended` method, though is a little simpler/less intensive. They both work just finr.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer (and rcollyer) Both work just fine for the MWE (which is all I can ask for) but imo using Legended means that one does not have to define a contour (and an equation) and can just use any list of points to superpose onto a contour. Anyway thank you both!

Comment: @OldTomMorris actually, [Brett's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179639/52) is the correct one. `Column` was causing the confusion.

Comment: @rccollyer In that case, I have shifted the answer. Thanks also to you, though.

Answer (score 3):

Each plot type allows only specific legends to be used with `PlotLegends`, for `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot` it is `BarLegend`. So, it is getting confused when you add `LineLegend`. (Per [Marius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179634/52), there is a switchover to `LineLegend` when only specific contours are used, e.g. `f == g` form of input to `ContourPlot`.)

The correct way is to use `Legended` to add the additional legend:

```
Legended[
 ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], 
  Epilog -> {{Red, Line[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0., 3., .1}]]}}]
 , 
 LineLegend[{Directive[Red]}, {"Test"}]
]
```

Comment: This the one. I just managed to concoct something from Marius' answer and comments and I used Show and Legended. Was about to post an answer when I see your simplified result. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Hacked it. The key was to use LegendLabel to label the BarLegend and then hack it into what I wanted.

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[y + x] x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> 
BarLegend[Automatic, 
 LegendLabel -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Red]}, {"Test"}], Bottom]], 
Epilog -> {{Red, Line[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0., 3., .1}]]}}]
```

The result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORkJ.jpg